# How to download the latest build artifacts from Azure DevOps via REST API without mentioning buildId?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-rest-api

URl mention in documentation:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=4.1

How to get the buildid via REST API or can we download the artifact without buildId

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me, it was on preview back then:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?branchName={branchName}&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Comment: How to get definition?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

Answer (score 0):

The following API gets a specific artifact for a build:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=5.1
```

You could get a list of builds, including buildid via the following API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1

With optional parameters:

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&queues={queues}&buildNumber={buildNumber}&minTime={minTime}&maxTime={maxTime}&requestedFor={requestedFor}&reasonFilter={reasonFilter}&statusFilter={statusFilter}&resultFilter={resultFilter}&tagFilters={tagFilters}&properties={properties}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&maxBuildsPerDefinition={maxBuildsPerDefinition}&deletedFilter={deletedFilter}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&branchName={branchName}&buildIds={buildIds}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&api-version=5.1
```

While the following API gets the latest build for a definition, optionally scoped to a specific branch:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?branchName={branchName}&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

You could get a list of definitions:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1

With optional parameters:

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?name={name}&repositoryId={repositoryId}&repositoryType={repositoryType}&queryOrder={queryOrder}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&minMetricsTime={minMetricsTime}&definitionIds={definitionIds}&path={path}&builtAfter={builtAfter}&notBuiltAfter={notBuiltAfter}&includeAllProperties={includeAllProperties}&includeLatestBuilds={includeLatestBuilds}&taskIdFilter={taskIdFilter}&processType={processType}&yamlFilename={yamlFilename}&api-version=5.1
```